# Export icons of android specified dimensions in Illustrator

Tags: android, adobe-illustrator, android-icons

I have prepared my desired app launcher icon in Adobe Illustrator. I cannot get the software to export icons of google prescribed dimensions :
[image]

Using the "Export for Screens" options just generates icons in various multiples of the designed icon which are incorrect sizes. If I resize the entire design in the software workspace, the design gets disrupted. Using "Save for Web" options does not produce the required bitmap depth of 32 bits. Can someone suggest what to do ?

Comment: design the icon with larger dimension and generate the icons using this website, it might be helpful.... https://makeappicon.com/ or http://assets.codly.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Illustrator are you using?
On my computer, if you click the drop-down triangle in the "export for screen", there're options to input the size.

I use the latest version. If yours doesn't have the option, perhaps use adobe cloud to update will help?

[image: Options to input image size]